# Signal King Mac Drivers

Tags: networking, mac, wifi-configuration, antenna

I've now accumulated two Wi-Fi antennas for the purpose of going on a neighbor's shared secure network. The first (an *Ideaworks* outdoor antenna) works ok (middling would be a kind descriptor to apply) but is Windows only and we are limited on when and where my work machine (the Windows box) is.

So I recently picked up a *Signal King* (looks like [this model](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007M7RP6Q)) and it actually seems to work great for Windows but I'm having the damnedest time getting it to work with my MacBook (running Mountain Lion)

I've tried installing a few different things from the Thai SignalKing site with no luck.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Any chance you could tell us what exactly you installed or did as advised by the Signal King website? Mainly so that you aren't getting the same advice saying "install this" when you've already tried it.

Comment: I've already undone all that I previously did, so consider me in blank slate state